# PHP: pushing new data (including new key) in associative array

Tags: php, arrays, push, associative-array

So I am trying to push new data into an array. This data inlcudes new key values.

This is what I am using now, however this will always overwrite the last with the newer in stead of adding a row to the array:

```
foreach ($arr AS $lineNum => $line) {

    list($key, $value) = explode(':', $line);
    $newArray[$key] = $value;

}

return $newArray;
```

So what can I do to chop these up?

Comment: `$key` will ever be same ?

Comment: key is not at all possible to be same.. latest key will overwrite that

Comment: What data are you feeding into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
//try this it won't overwrite

$i = 0;

foreach ($arr AS $lineNum => $line) {

    $i = count($newArray);

    list($key, $value) = explode(':', $line);
    $newArray[$i] = $value;
    $i++;

}

return $newArray;
```

Comment: instead if `$i`, `array_push` or even `$newArray[] = $value` would work, but OP specified he's dealing with an _associative_ array